# scientific plotting software like Excel with more functionality without coding?

Tags: publications

Is there any (popular) software for Mac that generates high quality scientific plots for publications without needs for coding? Specifically, I am looking to generate sub-plots or panels where Excel does not have such functionality.

Seems Plot is one good choice:

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20194/plot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about academia but software.

Comment: This question should probably be asked on [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

Comment: DO NOT ANALYZE YOUR DATA USING EXCEL!!!!According to [this article, and many others](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/sifter/one-five-genetics-papers-contains-errors-thanks-microsoft-excel), "One in five genetics papers contains errors thanks to Microsoft Excel".

Answer (score 1):

You can look at some online services such as [Plotly](https://plot.ly/), which works with Excel, R, etc.